# S3 Batch Operations - "Reading the manifest is forbidden: Access Denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup PUT COPY S3 Batch Operations Job. I'm following the AWS guide exactly how it's written, but every time I'm greeted with the Status: Failed with failure reason: "Reading the manifest is forbidden: AccessDenied".

I've managed to get it work by doing the job with IAM role that has AdministratorAccess policy, but I would like to get that working with a little less permissions. I've tried setting permissions with giving permissions "Allow *" for the three buckets (Source, Destination and Manifest) and all the files inside them ("ARN" and "ARN/*"), but that doesn't work. Even AmazonS3FullAccess (Allow s3: *) gives the same error.

I'm out of ideas, how to continue with this. Apparently the role needs more permissions, but what?

Answer (score 7):

Also, for your custom IAM role or even for `AdministratorAccess` policy, you need to make sure the IAM you are using has `batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com` under **Trusted entities**:

[image]

Click **Edit trust relationship** and add this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Any idea if this is this new?  First time I've had to edit trust policy on a role but I've definitely run S3 Batch before...

Comment: I think this was always there. You might have managed to make this work by using a role that was using a trust relationship something like: "Principal": { "Service": "*" }. But I haven't tried this out so, just a theory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due disabled STS (IAM - Account settings - enable) in that particular region which was concerned with the S3 Batch job.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding **s3:GetObjectVersion** permission on the manifest bucket for **batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com**.
This permission is currently not listed in all parts of the documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-iam-role-policies.html

Replicate existing objects: InitiateReplication with a S3 generated manifest

```
    {
         "Action":[
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::*** manifest bucket ***/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::*** completion report bucket ****/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::*** manifest bucket ****/*"    
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are supplying path to manifest.json filem but it also needs to read all the csv files related to that manifest json. So supply access to the manifest folder.

instead of

```
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{MANIFEST_KEY}"
         ]
```

do

```
"Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{FOLDER_WITH_ALL_MANIFEST_FILES}"
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer - Creating the Inventory File (manifest.json) into same bucket as the files to be copied made the trick.